# MYSQL Multidimensional Group_Concat based on 2 qualifiers

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-concat

Here is my data

[image]

I need to group by data_id and run a select query so that the data returns in this fashion, using data_id=2 as an example.

```
optics_finish:3673|optics_reticle:3923,3924
```

Using group_concat, I have been successful in getting all the data but it returns like this:

```
optics_finish:3673|optics_reticle:3923|optics_reticle:3924
```

But the thing is that I cannot repeat the attribute code. I need a group within a group and I keep getting the error Invalid use of a group function.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be immensely helpful if you'd post the query you've used, but anyway... I think I was able to get the results you're looking for with the following query

```
SELECT data_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', attribute_code, IDs) SEPARATOR '|') AS concatMess
FROM 
(
    SELECT data_id, attribute_code, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute_id SEPARATOR ',') AS `IDs` 
    FROM data 
    WHERE 1 
    GROUP BY attribute_code
) sq 
GROUP BY data_id;
```

Note: The `SEPARATOR ','` isn't really necessary, but I like to be explicit. Feel free to remove it

Results:

```
data_id    concatMess
   1    manufacturer:148
   2    optics_finish:3673|optics_reticle:3923,3924
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I popped it into my subquery and it seems to be working perfect. I will accept the answer once I fully test it out. However, I don't understand the "WHERE 1" line. Whats the purpose there?

Comment: @ShawnAbramson Again, I like to be explicit and include all basic clauses. `WHERE 1` just means that it's going to pull all data. It also serves as a placeholder in case you want to actually add a query condition

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
select data_id,
       concat_wc('|',
                 group_concat(case when attribute_code = 'optics_finish' then attribute_id end),
                 group_concat(case when attribute_code = 'optics_reticle' then attribute_id end)
                ) as attributes
from table t
group by data_id
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. While I see the logic in this, the attribute_code column can be of many different values. If I were limited to the two attribute_codes you see in the sample data, this would be a ton easier. Thanks for the try!